# Catch2 Framework Error: unknown type name 'DNA'clang-tidy(clang-diagnostic-error)

Tags: c++, constructor, catch2

I'm using catch2 framework for unit testing. Below is the command I use for compiling the test file.

`bin/tests: ./tests/tests.cc ./src/dna_strand.cc ./includes/dna_strand.hpp $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ./tests/tests.cc ./src/dna_strand.cc -o $@`

I'm trying to initialize constructor. I'm trying to use the class' method but it does not work. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my includes.
I also tried to initialize my DNAstrand class but it keeps throwing the same error.

Below is the code:

```
#ifndef CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#  define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#endif


#include <catch/catch.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "dna_strand.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"

DNAstrand sample();
sample.PushNode('h'); // <- error

DNAstrand\* DNA = new DNAstrand();
DNA->SpliceIn('h'); // <- error

TEST_CASE("Does nothing", "\[does-nothing\]") { REQUIRE(true == true);
```

Belows are the 4 errors I get

```
unknown type name 'sample'
cannot use dot operator on a type
unknown type name 'DNA'
cannot use arrow operator on a type
```

Comment: Two things: First; In any case, you should include more information like the exact error you're getting. Second; You're missing the main function. C++ does not allow code outside of functions

Comment: @Tidemor I just edited my question. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow code outside of functions (excluding definitions and declarations), meaning you need to move your code inside the TEST_CASE macro.

Comment: In my class, we are using catch2 framework. For the past assignments, I didn't put `void main' function for testing file.

Comment: in that case, everything that's happening should be moved into the body of the TEST_CASE macro.